# How to search contents of one file in another file which are not exists

Tags: shell, unix, grep, command

I have one file (FILEA) which is having 1000000 IMEI numbers. I have another file (FILEB) which is having 5 times more than fILEA records. That means 5000000 lines.

`FILEA` looks like below:

```
1234567790
4567834456
5566898954
5656788856
```

`FILEB` looks like below:

```
1234567790 ABABDHKDHDJS
2222222222 RHJEOSBHOWHW
5566898954 DGJRIWCNISKS
5656788856 GHEUNDBUEOKK
```

Now i want all the IMEI lists which are not present in FILEA

So my output should another file which will look like below.

`FILEC` looks like

```
2222222222 RHJEOSBHOWHW
```

something like below which whould work faster as well.

```
grep -f File_1 File_2 > File_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } !($1 in a)' filea fileb > filec
```

Results:

```
2222222222 RHJEOSBHOWHW
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your comment. however it is giving me below error.   awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @user2642751: Works fine for me using `gawk`, `mawk` and `nawk`. What flavour and version of `awk` are you using?

Comment: @user2642751: Just a random guess, but are you using Solaris? If so, you may need to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead of `awk`. Regardless, I would install GNU `awk` sooner rather than later if I were you. It will save a lot of time/effort in the long run.